# How to run an android TV app on real TV

Tags: android, android-tv

I am in the process of learning android TV programming. I want to get the hardware needed ready. However on the website http://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start.html
I can only find the guideline to run on emulator. I am curious how can I run an app on an real TV.

When developing for android phone. I need to use a usb cable to connect to the phone and enable usb debugging on the phone. What about running on TV?

And what features need the TV have? I assume the TV need some smart feature and some kind of android runtime platform. How can I facilitate this?

If I don't have any smart TV, can I use a non-smart TV with some interface to do developing?

Answer (score 4):

When you connect your android TV/Box to a network through wifi/LAN Cable, go to network settings-get the advanced options-select ip settings-chose static ip address. give a static ip for example 10.10.14.219
save it.
then go to your studio terminal- type 'yum install adb' press enter
after the installation process -in terminal -

```
'adb kill-server'
```

press enter then

```
'adb start-server'
```

press enter.then

```
'adb connect 10.10.14.219'
```

your device will be connected to the studio. then you can run the application directly to TV/box as like you do in the mobile with usb.

Comment: Use this link to get details of the static ip adress    [https://www.digitalstacks.org/set-static-ip-android-smartphone/]

Answer (score 3):

> What about running on TV?

That documentation is for Android TV. You need an Android TV device, such as the Nexus Player.

> And what features need the TV have?

That will depend upon your Android TV device. If the Android TV device is separate from the TV, like the Nexus Player, you need whatever the Android TV device says you need (usually, just an HDMI port). There are supposed to be TVs coming up that have Android TV as part of the TV itself, but I do not know if there are any such TVs available today.

> I use a non-smart TV with some interface to do developing?

You can buy an Android TV "set-top box", like the Nexus Player.

Comment: Thanks. Then the TV here is essentially an monitor.

Comment: @darklord: Yes. It can literally be a monitor, or a projector. The "TV" in "Android TV" is more the expected consumer use case, not a requirement of the capabilities of what the Android TV device is connected to.

Comment: @CommonsWare Hi, can I run my own Android TV app on every HDMI stick that runs Android? Can I just plug the stick into my computer, select the HDMI-stick as Device in Android Studio and plug it into the TV?

Comment: @Androidicus: "can I run my own Android TV app on every HDMI stick that runs Android?" -- I have no idea. "Can I just plug the stick into my computer, select the HDMI-stick as Device in Android Studio and plug it into the TV?" -- ideally, yes. If that does not work for some given device, take it up with the manufacturer.

Answer (score -1):

```
There are multiple ways, but basically people use below of them
1) Screen mirroring
2) HDMI

How to use
1)- If you use screen mirroring then your device have screen mirroring support and device also support, this technology used wifi.
2)- If you use HDMI then you need android mini pc device which have atleast kitkat 4.4 version and using hdmi cable you can use.
```

Comment: The Question is about connecting android studio via adb.